# will using credit card a lot help building credit score?

Tags: credit-card, united-kingdom, credit-score, credit-report, credit-limit

I have a credit card with a very low limit, which I finish regularly in a very limited time. will using it to the limit and pay the balance several time per one statement help to build the credit score and increase the limit.

If not, I should probably use the credit card until I reach the limit and start using the debit card, because it's annoying to monitor the usage and pay the balance every couple of days. but it worth it if this help to increase the limit quickly and build up the credit score.

Comment: Just ask the institution for a higher limit; they're always happy to lend more money.

Comment: not if I am new to the country and have no credit history @JohnMee

Comment: What country are you in?  In the US it wouldn't matter, all you need is a non-zero balance and then to pay it so you get a paid-as-agreed posted to your credit report.

Comment: It's hard to predict exactly when a credit card company will let you increase the limit, but yes, in general using it and paying it off will increase your odds of getting the limit increased.

Comment: I am in the UK.

Comment: No credit card spend alone willn't add to your score. Have you tried obtaining your credit report from one of the agencies ? And your length of stay in the country affects a lot. If you arrived only last year, then don't expect that you have a great credit score. By time your score will build up with good credit behaviour. Try using your debit card too, that also gets into your credit report.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a credit card with a very low limit, which I finish regularly in a very limited time. will using it to the limit and pay the balance several time per one statement help to build the credit score and increase the limit

Generally the feeds to Credit Bureau are once a month. So if you are paying several times a month and utilizing it, this does not show up. In case of cards the outstanding Balance, Credit limit, days past due, Card Opening Date, etc are reported. Thus in your case, this will not increase your credit limit. Most Credit Scoring agencies track Utilization, i.e. Overall Limit to Balance due. The less the utilization the better the score.

Hence if you are looking to increase your score, it would help to get a better limit on the card to drive down the utilization ratio.